# Ошибка IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, рефлексия

Суть работы: есть пакет, в котором генерируется массив чисел и еще один пакет, в котором происходит сортировка массива. Нужно реализовать модуль, который автоматически будет находит массив из пакета(по аннотации @Filler) и сортировать его, прогоняя этот массив через  класс, в котором происходит сортировка (этот класс унаследован от класса Sort)
пробую реализовать этот самый "модуль":

```
public class Analyzer{
    public static void runAllAnnotatedMethods() throws Exception {
         Class<?> c = Class.forName("fillers.ArrayFiller");
         Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : m) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Filler.class)) {
                ArrayFiller a = (ArrayFiller) method.invoke(new ArrayFiller[]{});//static method
                Set<Class<? extends Sort>> subTypesOf = (new Reflections("sorters")).getSubTypesOf(Sort.class);
                for (Class c1 : subTypesOf){
                    Method[] m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethods();
                    for (Method method1 : m1) {
                        if (a != null) {
                            method1.invoke(a, new ArrayFiller[]{});//non static method
                        }
                    }
                }
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at analyzer.Analyzer.runAllAnnotatedMethods(Analyzer.java:21)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

что не правильно я делаю?

вот класс fillers.ArrayFiller и аннотированный метод:

```
public class ArrayFiller {

    @Filler
    public static void randomized(int[]a) {
        a = new int[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, класс (`fillers.ArrayFiller`) и аннотированный метод.

Comment: При вызове статического метода нужно писать `method.invoke(null, args...)`, ибо первый параметр - это всегда объект, для которого выполняется метод.

Comment: @AlexChermenin исправила. но ошибка осталась

Comment: Все-таки непонятно. Вы вызываете метод `void randomized(int[]a)` и пытаетесь результат (которого нет) привести к `ArrayFiller`. Можете объяснить что Вы хотели сделать в строке 7?

Comment: @defaultlocale похоже что я не правильно понимаю весь процесс. Мне не нужно приводить массив к ArrayFiller. Надо передать этот массив а  и сортировать его, прогоняя этот массив через класс, в котором происходит сортировка.

Comment: @НаташаБойченко насколько я понял, ошибка возникает уже при вызове `randomized`. Поправьте, если не так.

Comment: @defaultlocale да, при вызове randomized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не отметили строку, на которой возникает ошибка (`Analyzer.java:21`), полагаю что это вызов `randomized`:

```
ArrayFiller a = (ArrayFiller) method.invoke(new ArrayFiller[]{});
```

Вижу как минимум две проблемы. Скорее всего действительно придется пересмотреть процесс:

1. [`Method.invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) принимает два аргумента:

   - `obj` — объект от которого выполняется метод, для статических методов игнорируется;
   - `args` — аргументы, которые нужно передать в метод.

   Соответственно, строка:

   ```
   ArrayFiller a = (ArrayFiller) method.invoke(new ArrayFiller[]{})
   ```

   для статического метода проигнорирует переданный пустой массив, попытается выполнить метод без аргументов, и будет ожидать `ArrayFiller` в качестве результата. Так можно выполнить метод с сигнатурой:

   ```
   static ArrayFiller createArrayFiller();
   ```

   в то время как `randomized` принимает аргумент и ничего не возвращает. Ошибка говорит о несоответствии аргументов.
2. Метод `randomized` ничего не делает.

   В `randomized` создается новый объект, который присваевается переменной-аргументу функции. Соответственно, переданный в метод объект (если он был передан) не изменится.

   Это можно проверить без рефлексии, выполнив такого кода:

   ```
   int[] a = new int[1];
   ArrayFiller.randomize(a);
   System.out.println(a.length); //1
   ```

   объект на который ссылается переменная `a` никак не изменился.

   Рекомендую тщательно отладить поведение методов в `ArrayFiller` прежде чем приниматься за их автоматизацию.

**Исправление:**

Для начала понадобится возвращать значение из `randomized`. Метод никак не использует аргумент, его можно убрать:

```
@Filler
public static int[] randomized() {
    int[] a = new int[10000];
    //... здесь заполнение
    return a;
}
```

такой метод можно вызвать при помощи рефлексии, не передавая аргументов:

```
int[] array = (int[]) method.invoke(null);
```

Что там дальше с сортировкой не ясно, предлагаю выправить заполнить и если после этого возникнут вопросы, то разбираться с ними отдельно.

Comment: Я все сделала, как Вы описали, вроде все хорошо, но теперь такая же ошибка в строке           method1.invoke(a);    Нужно еще что-то передавать в invoke?

Comment: @НаташаБойченко блин, вы не догоняете немного))) метод `invoke` вызывает метод объекта `a`. НО! Сто пудово у этого `method1` есть какие-то аргументы, которые вам и надо передать в `invoke`, например `method1.invoke(object, argument1)`

Comment: @lampa конечно не догоняю, потому сюда и пишу) Не могу понять, ведь этот argument1 и есть тот массив a, который извлекается int[] a = (int[]) method.invoke(null);. в качестве аргумента надо передать тот массив, который я извлекла в начале.

Comment: @НаташаБойченко если `a` это аргумент, то перед ним должен быть либо объект, если вы вызываете нестатичный метод, либо `null`, если `method1` - статичный метод.

Comment: @lampa метод не статичный. Какой именно объект надо передать я пока не понимаю.

Comment: @НаташаБойченко как я написал, с `method1` и классами сортировки я даже не начал разбираться. Попробуйте взять один из этих классов и выполнить его отдельно от других, передав массив. Если не разберетесь самостоятельно, то можно задать вопрос, но пожалуй лучше отдельно от этого, т.к. проблема в этом вопросе уже решена. Тем более, что для того чтобы разобраться в новой проблеме потребуется доп. информация: данные по ошибке, откуда берется класс `Reflections` и что он делает, примеры классов-сортировщиков и их методов.

Comment: @defaultlocale попробую разобраться дальше сама! спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @НаташаБойченко Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

Так, смотрите:

```
Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Вы находите все методы, в принципе ничего сложного.
Дальше вы вызываете все методы в цикле, но т.к. в `ArrayFiller` всего 1 метод, то вызывается соответственно только он, `public static void randomized(int[]a)`. Тут тоже всё понятно.

Поехали дальше. В следующей строке вы пытаетесь вызвать статичный метод.

```
ArrayFiller a = (ArrayFiller) method.invoke(new ArrayFiller[]{});
```

Чтобы вызывать статичный метод, метод `invoke` первым аргументом должен принимать `null`, а вторым массив `int[] a`. У вас же передается новый объект и не передается массив, т.е.:

```
method.invoke(null, new int[]{});
```

Но у вас же метод `randomized` определен как `void`, т.е. не возвращает значения, а передавать какой-либо массив `int[]` бесполезно, ведь он заново инициализируется:

```
public static void randomized(int[]a) {
        a = new int[10000];
```

---

Я не до конца понял, что делает этот участок кода:

```
Set<Class<? extends Sort>> subTypesOf = (new Reflections("sorters")).getSubTypesOf(Sort.class);
    for (Class c1 : subTypesOf){
    Method[] m1 = c1.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method1 : m1) {
        if (a != null) {
            method1.invoke(a, new ArrayFiller[]{});//non static method
        }
    }
}
```

Но в целом вы ведь получаете список каких-то классов, которые наследуются в `ArrayFiller`, ведь вы пытаетесь вызвать методы классов `subTypesOf` на экземпляр `ArrayFiller`:

```
method1.invoke(a, new ArrayFiller[]{});
```

В общем не понятно, что должно быть в итоге и что представляет из себя `ArrayFiller`, для чего он.

Comment: Про статичный метод поняла, спасибо. В классе ArrayFiller происходит создание рандомного массива определенной длинны. А указанный Вами участок кода должен принимать этот рандомный массив и предавать его в  класс, где этот массив будет сортироваться. После того, как я правильно реализую рефлексию, в нее будет добавлен  long start = System.nanoTime();  long count = System.nanoTime() - start; и будет выстроена статистика по времени выполнения сортировки(их несколько видов) массива